# Different TTL per document using Spring Data MongoDB @Indexed annotation

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

I know that with Spring Data for MongoDB you can set a document to be deleted:

```java
    @Indexed(name = "ttl", expireAfterSeconds = 12)
    private LocalDateTime expireAfterSeconds;
```

or

```java
    @Indexed(name = "ttl", expireAfter = "12s")
    private LocalDateTime expireAfterSeconds;
```

Those documents will be deleted after the time specified in the annotation, it will be the same for every document that gets created.

I would like to understand if it's possible to still create a TTL index but the value can be calculated for each document. (Like in DynamoDB you'd pass an epoch time in seconds)

Something like

```java
@Document("groceryitems")
public class GroceryItem {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(name = "deleteThisRecordAfter", expireAfter = "@checkActualValue")
    private LocalDateTime expireAfter;

    // or
    @Indexed(name = "deleteThisRecordAfter", ttlIndex = true)
    /*
    * ttlIndex = true doesn't exist,
    * but I would like to only have a TTL index and then provide a value for the field
    * that mongod will use to determine when to delete the document.
     */
    private LocalDateTime expireAfter;

    public GroceryItem(String id, LocalDateTime expireAfter) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.expireAfter = expireAfter;
    }
}
```

```java
    public persist(Item item) {
        repository.save(new GroceryItem(item.getId(), getCorrectTTL(item.getExpirationDate(), item.getCategory())));
    }
```

Comment: I'm a little confused by the premise of the question. Deletion of documents via a TTL index is indeed done _per document_. From [the documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-ttl/#expiration-of-data): "_TTL indexes expire documents after the specified number of seconds has passed since the indexed field value; i.e. the expiration threshold is the indexed field value plus the specified number of seconds._" So I think the solution to your problem is to set the appropriate value for each document? If not can you further clarify on what you're trying to do?